# How to extract string in a line

Tags: bash, shell

I have get following string, and I want to get the result of the status string '0/3',

```
        NAME                         READY   AGE
        statefulset.apps/zookeeper   0/3     145m
```

How to get the number string '0/3' in the column READY?

```
      0/3
```

Now, I'm using the

```
  echo "statefulset.apps/zookeeper   0/3     145m" | grep -o -P '(?<=statefulset.apps/zookeeper   ).*(?=[(\s+).*])'
```

any way to use the awk instead of grep? also there are blank space in the result. Thank you.

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/awk/example/28060/extract-specific-column-field-from-specific-line

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=extract+string+from+line

Comment: `awk '$1 ~ /^statefulset.apps\/zookeeper/ { print $2 }' file`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you, any way to pass the string as argument?   like:   zk_status=$(awk '$1 ~ /^ARGV[1]/ { print $2 }' all.log)       it will take 'statefulset.apps/zookeeper' as parameter, thank you again.

Comment: Yes, `awk -v str="$str_from_shell" '... rest of command...'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extract the content of a column, you can do the following.

***remark:** We assume that the field separator `FS` equals to the string `"fs"`. You can replace this by anything, or if you just use <blanks> as field separator, you can remove the `BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs"}` part in any of the following solutions.*

**extract column `n` of line `m`,upto and including line `m`, from line `m` onewards:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs"}(FNR==m){print $n}' file
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs"}(FNR<=m){print $n}' file
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs"}(FNR>=m){print $n}' file
```

**extract `n`th last column of line `m`,upto and including line `m`, from line `m` onewards:**

This can be handy when you don't have the same amount of columns per line

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs"}(FNR==m){print $(NF-n+1)}' file
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs"}(FNR<=m){print $(NF-n+1)}' file
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs"}(FNR>=m){print $(NF-n+1)}' file
```

**extract all columns upto and including `n` of line `m`,upto and including line `m`, from line `m` onewards:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs"}(FNR==m){s="";for(i=1;i<=n;++i) s=s (s?OFS:"") $(a[i])}' file
```

**extract columns `n1` < `n2` < ... < `nk`:, of line `m`,upto and including line `m`, from line `m` onewards:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs"; k=split("n1,n2,n3,...,nk",a,",")}
     (FNR==m){s="";for(i=1;i<=k;++i) s=s (s?OFS:"") $(a[i])}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you can use awk :)

I tested with:

```
~ ❯ kubectl get pods
NAME                                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-ingress-xxx                                  1/1     Running   0          2d
nginx-ingress-xxx                                  1/1     Running   1          73d
```

Try this:

```
kubectl get pods | awk 'NR > 1 {print $2}'
```

To only retrieve the strings:

```
1/1
1/1
```

If you want only 1 line, feels free to modify the command to something like:

```
kubectl get pods | awk 'NR == 2 {print $2}'
```

**Note:** 
kubectl is only an example, replace it with your command.

Have a nice day